# Errors with Shared Memory and Semaphores in C

Tags: c, posix, ipc, shared-memory, semaphore

I'm attempting to recreate the Producer/Consumer problem.  What I've got so far is the main program creating shared memory using SystemV and a semaphore using POSIX, to test if the producer process can access it.
Here is my code so far:

boundedbuffer.c

```
#define SHMKEYPATH = "/dev/null" 
#define SHMKEYID 1
#define SEMKEYPATH = "/dev/null"
#define SEMKEYID 1

//Create Shared Memory
int shmid;
key_t shmkey;
void *shmaddress;
char *shm;

shmkey = ftok(SHMKEYPATH, SHMKEYID);
shmid = shmget(shmkey, sizeof(int) * 5, IPC_CREAT | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
shmaddress = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
shm = (char*)(shmaddress);
*shm = 'b';
printf("Test share memory: currently %c",*shm);

//Create Semaphore
sem_t* my_semaphore;
char SEMAPHORE_NAME[] = "/my_semaphore5";
int my_semvalue = 10;
int value;

my_semaphore = sem_open(SEMAPHORE_NAME, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, my_semvalue);
sem_getvalue(my_semaphore, &value);
printf("sem val is %d\n", value);

//Execute Producer Process
int Ppid = fork();
if(Ppid == 0)
    execv("PATHTOPRODUCER", NULL);

//Print values from producer
shm = (char*)(shmaddress);
printf("%s", shm);

shmdt(shmaddress);
shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);

sem_getvalue(my_semaphore, &value);
printf("New val is %d", value);
sem_close(my_semaphore);
sem_unlink(SEMAPHORE_NAME);
```

producer.c

```
//Test shared memory
void *shm_address;
int semid, shmid, rc;
key_t shmkey;

shkey = ftok(SHMKEYPATH, SHMKEYID);
shmid = shmget(shmkey, sizeof(int) *5, IPC_CREAT | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
shm_address = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
char *shm;
shm = (char*)(shm_address);
shm = "testing";
shmdt(shm_address);
```

There are two problems.  The producer is changing the shared memory but when I ask bounded buffer to tell me what the memory is, it is the same as before.  This was working at one point but no longer wants to work.  For the semaphores, I have no idea how to access them from the producer without creating a new one.

I'm been searching for a long time but all I can find are both POSIX or both SystemV solutions, not one with POSIX for semaphores and SystemV for shared memory (I have to use them, it's homework).

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: So the shared memory works if I replace the last 4 lines (except the last) with strcpy((char*)shm_address, "testing");  Why is this?  Still can't get semaphores to work.

Comment: You can sem_open the semaphores from the consumer in the same way - by name.  Don't use the O_EXCL flag else the open of an exiting semaphore will fail.

Comment: @MartinJames but what do I put for the last value, the initial value one?

Comment: For bounded P-C queues, it's usual to use two semaphores, one to count the number of items queued, init. to 0, and one to count the number of spaces left in the queue, init. to [queue size].  Another synchro object, either a mutex or sema init. to 1, is usually used to protect the queue from multiple accesses.  I've never implemented an inter-process queue, (only inter-thread), so I'm not actually answering:(

Comment: @MartinJames I know, I'm just testing out the shared memory and semaphores to make sure they're working properly before I fully implement this.  I've got the semaphore working for the producer now; it will take the main value and I can increment it.  However the incrementing will not reflect in the main program.  Any idea why this is?

Comment: For instance, I'm not at all sure if you really need to use a sem_open in the forked producer, (not sure if POSIX semaphores can be inherited), but using a separate sem_open is safer:)

Comment: @MartinJames if they can be (inherited) its news to me. I always open mine on both sides with proper setup. Lord knows I may have been doing to the "hard" way all this time, but I doubt it.